# how do I get an image from the Media library using RendingModel

Tags: mvc

I am new to using the RenderingModel, preferably I would just use a strongly typed model, but my company wants to keep things thin and out of the box, here is my code, I just need to understand how to get the media library image

```
@model RenderingModel

@{ 
    var image = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Feature Image", Model.Item);

}

<div class="col-sm-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="@image"></div>
```

Comment: I believe this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828908/get-media-url-in-view-in-sitecore-mvc

Please confirm if this is so; and we can close this question.

Comment: It is but that is not what I am doing, my above example is in the View

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark mentioned, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828908/get-media-url-in-view-in-sitecore-mvc) provides you with one answer, using extension methods.

I believe what you want is simpler tho. The `@Html.Sitecore().Field(....)` method will return you a fully rendered `<img>` tag. So you can just use that in your mark up:

```
@model RenderingModel

<div class="col-sm-6">
    @Html.Sitecore().Field("Feature Image", Model.Item, new { @class = "img-responsive" })
</div>
```

Notice that you can pass in a new dynamic object to the field renderer, that dynamic object will be converted to attributes on the rendered image.

This would render out to:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="~/media/path-to-your-image.ashx" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Comment: you are correct sir, I figured that out. I have been working with sitecore on and off for 6 years and every implementation is different than the last.