# Image and link fields rendering as raw values

Tags: mvc, fieldtype

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 and attempting to render Image and General Link fields as recommended in [this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/how-do-i-get-an-image-from-the-media-library-using-rendingmodel):

```
@model Company.Feature.Foo.Models.FooBarViewModel
...
@Html.Sitecore().Field("{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000}")
@Html.Sitecore().Field("{83d6de54-019d-4774-bfd9-ce79e0802a24}")
```

But the resulting HTML is just the raw field values:

```
<image mediaid="{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000}" />
<link text="Something" linktype="internal" class="bar" querystring=""
      target="" id="{83d6de54-019d-4774-bfd9-ce79e0802a24}">
```

I've also tried the following and they don't work. The only difference I can see compared with the post I linked is that I'm using a custom `@model` class rather than `RenderingModel`.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("{123e4567-...}", Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem)
@Html.Sitecore().Field("FieldName", Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem)
```

To get around this, I've had to write my own HTML Helpers that only partially implement what Sitecore could do. Is this a known issue with the standard renderer and does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Can you give more details around what your view model looks like? Does it inherit from `RenderingModel`?

Comment: You cannot use the Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem as it is not your model. Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem current rendering item or if no data source rendering item selected then it returns the current page as item.

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your cshtml file?